# Midnight Commander - default directory after shell link?

Tags: ssh, mc

When I connect to a remote host via mc's Shell link, I always start at that host's root directory. Is there a way to specify that I want to start in a different directory, e.g. the home directory of the user I connect as?

If I just ssh to the host, I start at the home directory by default.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd sh://user@host:/any/path/you/want
```

Comment: is there a way to do it "shorter" for the usual use case: F9 > Shell link... > "hostname", and I'd like me to land in the home directory

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the starting directory by adding :/pathname after.

ex:
user@machine:/path/to/folder